# c++ multiple cin default value if not entered, adding to a map<string, vector<double>>

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, vector, cin

Tasks goes like this:
you should enter  name , price, amount in one line and if amount is not given the amount should be default 1. my problem is:
you should type in as many lines as you want if you for example type:
monkey 200 3
stingray 399 1

it works, but if you only mention name and price the amount should be added to the map with the amount 1 if any is not given. Instead ut jumps to the next and you input a string name on an int an the loop craches. Is there any other way to do this?

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
int main(){
   map<string, vector<double>> vec;
   string name;
   double price; 
   double amount;
   while(cin >> name >> price >> amount){
      vec[name] = {price , amount}
   }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The way you did, the user needs to enter the three fields, and amount seems to be optional. You need to read it as if it is a single string and then split it - if you find an amount, you go your default path. If not, you go to the alternative path.

Comment: okej, i have read about like getline command but how do i use it properly in my situation @LeonardoAlvesMachado

Comment: read in the line into a `string`.  load the `string` into a `stringstream` and then parse out the data.  If you are missing a filed the stream will go into an error state and then you know if the amount should be defaulted or not.

Comment: okej i will try that, please come with an example if you can :) @NathanOliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i soloved my own problem. this is my solution and it works with the parameters i mentioned in my question.

```
Firstclass myclass;
string item, data;
vector<string> split_input;

// reads in on line of string until ctrl-z/ctrl-d
while(getline(cin, data)){
    stringstream str_stream(data);
    // reading the values separate adding them to vector
    while(str_stream >> item{
        split_input.push_back(item);
    }
    // if amount is not given
    if(v.size() == 2){
        myclass.insert_data(split_input[0], stod(split_input[1]), 1.00);
    }
    // if if amount is given
    else{
        myclass.insert_data(split_input[0], stod(split_input[1]),   stod(split_input[2]));
    }
    // clearing the vector
    split_input.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>

int main(){
   map<string, vector<double>> vec;
   string name;
   double price; 
   double amount;
   int peek_;

   do{
      amount = 1;
      std::cin >> name >> price;
      std::cin >> std::ws; //get rid of white space
      int peek_ = cin.peek();
      if (std::isdigit(peek_)){
         std::cin >> amount;
      }
      vec[name] = {price , amount}
   } while (peek_ != EOF)

return 0;
}
```

This should give you the general idea. Also check [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/peek/) for more info.

Note: I wrote this on the go, so haven't compiled or tested. You might need to play a bit with the syntax :)

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks alot!  I will try this out!

Comment: i tried but cant get a hang of it , i needed to delcare peek_ outside the while loop asweel as isdigit(c) were changed to isdigit(peek_) , but when i am happy with the amout of lines you should be able to exit the loop with ctrl-D. and then i have a function that will print out the content of the map

Comment: My bad, don't know what I was thinking declaring `peek_` inside the loop lol